# Xpage JVM Debug Mode

Tags: debugging, jvm, xpages, lotus-domino

really funny situation. I need to turn off the debug mode in the http server in the Domino. More exactly to switch the Logger Level on the XPage.

Now in the Domino Log, there are many informations, which are not needed anymore.

Does somebody know, where to change the Logger Level in this situation?

Thanx

What i see for example is this, lowel level of logging:

```
    27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG -   Fire end() for RenderKitRule[className=com.sun.faces.config.beans.RenderKitBean]
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - [RenderKitRule]{faces-config/render-kit} Merge(HTML_BASIC)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.DataIterator,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapCustomView)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.DataIterator,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapForumView)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.Pager,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapPagerRenderer)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Dialog,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dialog.BootstrapDialog)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Dialog,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dialog.BootstrapDialog3)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Dialog,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dialog.BootstrapDialogButtonBar)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Dialog,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dialog.BootstrapDialogContent)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapAccordion)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapAccordion3)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapBreadCrumbs)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapDropDownButton)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapLinksList)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapOutlineMenu)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapSeparator)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Outline,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.outline.BootstrapSortLinks)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.Tooltip,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.tooltip.BootstrapTooltipRenderer)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.FormLayout,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapFormTable)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.ForumPost,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapForumPost)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.Pager,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapPagerAddRows)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.Pager,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapPagerDetail)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.Pager,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapPagerExpand)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.data.Pager,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.data.BootstrapPagerSizes)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.layout.ApplicationLayout,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.layout.BootstrapApplicationLayout)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.layout.ApplicationLayout,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.layout.BootstrapApplicationLayout3)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.picker.Picker,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.picker.BootstrapNamePicker)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.picker.Picker,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.picker.BootstrapNamePicker3)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.picker.Picker,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.picker.BootstrapValuePicker)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(com.ibm.xsp.extlib.picker.Picker,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.picker.BootstrapValuePicker3)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Input,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dojoext.form.BootstrapImageSelect)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Input,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dojoext.form.BootstrapLinkSelect)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Input,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dojoext.form.BootstrapListTextBox)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Input,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.dojoext.form.BootstrapNameTextBox)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Panel,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.containers.BootstrapInlineList)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Panel,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.containers.BootstrapWidgetContainer)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - addRenderer(javax.faces.Panel,org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.tagcloud.BootstrapTagCloud)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - characters(
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: )
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG - endElement(,,faces-config)
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG -   match='faces-config'
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: DEBUG -   bodyText='
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM:   
27.11.2015 22:06:12   HTTP JVM: '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check jvm/lib/ext folder in Domino server install folder. if some JAR file contains log4j.properties, it can be read and used by server

Comment: A yep this was the case. Really some sf4j jar library had a log4j.properties in it. What is very interesting is, that the server read it and took it for whole JVM (Xpage module as well).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked logging.properties as defined here? http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/10092008030107PMWDOJFJ.htm

Comment: Hi Paul, yep, everything seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove any entry with debug in the Domino Server configuration document and shutdown the Domino Server and remove any entry with debug in Notes.ini before fire it up again